# Does definition of an event depend on foreknowledge of probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume that a dice is tossed, the event $E_1$ that the outcome is odd number can be denoted as $E_1=\{O_1,O_3,O_5\}$. We know that the event $E_2$ that the outcome is number 7 is $E_2=\{\}$ (empty set) because $O_7$ can not happen. so the definition of event $E_2$ relies on the foreknowledge that $O_7$ can not happen. otherwise we would have denoted that as $E_2=\{O_7\}$    -- it has an element albeit its probability is 0.

Should definition of an event depends on foreknowledge of probability? should not only the opposite be true? 
how to understand "empty set has no element" in event definition context?

Comment: Let $E$ be the event that it will rain wherever you are now on July 13, 1,000,000,000 years from now. No way to know anything concerning this probability.  But you are talking about conditional probability. If $B$ is an impossible event, it does not belong to the sample space. $P(A|B)$, the probability that $A$ has occurred given that $B$ has occurred, in this case doesn't make sense.

Comment: it's okay that P(A|B) doesn't make sense. simply don't do that calculation. what I'd like to say is that the definition of events should not depend on the foreknowledge of their probability. thus, in a more natural and logical way of defining events, the impossible events should not be denoted as empty set and sample space should include those events.

Comment: The sample space cannot include events which cannot be outcomes. The definition of the sample space is the complete set of possible outcomes. Otherwise your sample space would be literally everything. Should "cat" be considered an event for a die roll? It makes sense to simplify things. Every event $E$ should be the same as the event $E\cap S$ where $S$ is the sample space. In other words, all events should be an element of $\mathcal{P}(S)$ (for finite). That is why it's called the "event space"

Comment: agree that simplifying things makes sense. but as a general definition, it shouldn't rely on knowing which events will not happen, as you mentioned in your first comment, you might not know whether some events are impossible or not before establishing the model and doing calculation.

Comment: in text books we are told that the empty set is any event that cannot occur. on the same page empty set is defined as subset of S that contains no elements. so it's a source of confusion.

Comment: That is true, because again given any set $E$, as an event $\bar E$ for a procedure having sample space $S$, $\bar E :=E\cap S$. You can form an equivalence relation to make it more obvious I suppose. Let $A$ and $B$ be any sets, and $S$ a sample space. Then $A\sim B$ iff $A\cap S = B\cap S$. We can call $\bar A=A\cap S$ the *event* in $\mathcal P(S)$ given by $A$. In this way $\bar A = \bar B$ as sets and hence events even if $A$ and $B$ are different, weird sets.

Comment: Yeah. so it's fair to say that an event and a set are two different entities, ditto impossible events v.s. empty set, or possible events v.s. sample space. the relationship between a event and a set is of a simplification mapping rather than by definition.

Comment: @David: "Should "cat" be considered an event for a die roll?". it shouldn't. I guess the dice is not a good example in this case, because the outcome is very limited and simple and deterministic. we know 7 is not going to be a outcome. but perhaps, in a more complex question, if the the event space just need to include all the value's in the same dimension (such as $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{R}$, etc), the representation will be more generic. the bottom line is: the probability theory is the method of operation for and is based on the knowledge the deterministic world...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to overcome your problem is to define probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ over $\sigma$-Algebra of events $\mathcal{F}$ defined as subsets of some set $\Omega$.

This is one way to define events prior to defining probability used in modern probability science and I will call it a formal tool of probability space.

Probability measure is any set function satisfying $\mathbb{P}(\emptyset) = 0 $ (Probability that nothing happens is $0$),$\mathbb{P}(\Omega) = 1$ (Probability that something happens at all is $1$) and that for any disjoint countable family of events $A$ we have $\mathbb{P}(\bigsqcup_n A_n) = \sum_n \mathbb{P}(A_n)$. For such measure you can have $\mathbb{P}(A) =0$ even if $A$ is not empty.

Depending on the peoblem you can select suitable probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. If you want formulate questions about dice in your example involving any natural numbers we can select $\Omega = \mathbb{N}$, $\mathcal{F} = 2^\mathbb{N}$ i. e. set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, and define $\mathbb{P}(\{1\}) = \frac{1}{6} \ldots \mathbb{P}(\{6\}) = \frac{1}{6}$ and for $n > 6$ $ \mathbb{P}(\{n\}) = 0 $. Using this definition you can extend $\mathbb{P}$ to all events in $\mathcal{F}$ which may involve complicated queries which actually might have zero probability. However, in this construction questions like $\mathbb{P}((1/2,3/5])$ are still not formally valid by construction of probability space.

Update:

Of course it wasn't implied in the answer that $\mathbb{P}(A) = 0$ implies that event $A$ is impossible.

**Example**: assume you are tossing darts into continuous interval $[0,1]$ without any aim. Eventually you hit some value, say $\sqrt{2}/3$. $\mathbb{P}(\{\sqrt{2}/3\}) = 0$, however it just has happened.

Concept of possibility seems to be mach more philosophical than mathematical. We can demand that for any true sample space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ for any $\omega \in \Omega$ event $\{\omega\}$ is possible. Call this **possibility property**. Then think about the dice as a map (random variable)  $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{N} $. With this definition we can say that $\mathbb{P}'(X \: \mathrm{is} \: 7) = \mathbb{P}\big(X^{-1}\{7\}\big) = \mathbb{P}(\emptyset)$, hence it is impossible for the dice to take value $7$. Here we think about $\mathbb{P}'$ as a push forward of $\mathbb{P}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ through $X$.  Note, that  $(\mathbb{N},2^\mathbb{N},\mathbb{P}')$ is a probability space in Kolmogorov axiomatics but it doesn't have the **possibility property**.

This can be a reason that most applications of probability theory works with random variables $X:\Omega \to S $ with sample space $\Omega$ left without any explicit description.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It seems to me the impossible events should not be expressed as a empty set and the sample space should include those impossible events. the probability measure is a function of the sample space. if the event is impossible or invalid, it simply means the probability of the event is 0.

Comment: @AlexL One problem with that is that the converse is not true: possible events needn't have positive probability. So reading off whether an event is possible from the probability structure is not possible. Another problem is that a routine example of an impossible event would be that two mutually exclusive events both occur. But under the standard probability space structure, we want "the event that $A$ and $B$ both happen" to be encoded by $A \cap B$...which in the mutually exclusive case is $\emptyset$.

Comment: @AlexL By the way, this is not just 'an idea' that Nik Pronko came up with, this the THE rigorous approach to probability used in modern mathematics. If you're serious about learning this, I'd recommend reading up on these concept.

Comment: @Ian I'm not sure if I got your point but a function requires only 1 main thing: there is ONE and ONLY ONE output for each input.

Comment: @AlexL I know what a function is. But you're trying to describe a "logically impossible event" in a way which is internal to the probability space structure. The problem is that a logically impossible event, such as two mutually exclusive events happening simultaneously, is encoded in the usual way by $\emptyset$, no matter what the description of the event actually was. To do something else you would need to formulate probability in a different way from the Kolmogorov axioms. Nothing inherently binds us to the Kolmogorov axioms but nothing else has really caught on the same way.

Comment: @Ian It seems to me that concept of impossible event is more philosophical than mathematical. In this post I tried to illuminate the problem from the classical axiomatic viewpoint. I also made an edit to remove all possible obfuscations.

Comment: @Nik. thanks for offering more thoughts in your update. I guess the expanded probability space $(\mathbb{N},2^\mathbb{N},\mathbb{P}')$ is the generic description I was looking for although it seems to make the solution of the question a bit more complicated. I hope a new system can be developed from this idea

Comment: @Nik. because, it seems, if we formulate the probability space in a usual way, we will have to know the boundary of the sample space which is not always easy or even not humanly possible (it is straightforward for dice but it's the most simple example). such study will help us to determine the probability only if we first know that certain event is possible, lacking that, we will not know where to start..

Comment: @Ian. I guess you think the idea illogical because you see it in the box of the traditional Kolmogorov axiomatic paradigm. it sure leads to conflicting assumptions.